# Who is Dixie, and why is she whistling?

Tags: idioms

> Until you nail that down, you're just whistling Dixie.

It sounds like such a weird thing to say. Who is that Dixie, why would I be her, and why in the world is she whistling?

Comment: [be whistling Dixie](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+whistling+Dixie)

Comment: Was it too hard to just [Google whistling Dixie?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=whistling+Dixie&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&oq=whistling+Dixie&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Closevoting for lack of research.

Comment: I *think* you're asking about the origin of this idiom, not it's meaning, which frankly isn't answered very definitively by a superficial reference search. If that's the case, you should edit your question to reflect that fact, including any research you did that was unsatisfactory.

Comment: @1006a: There's being charitable, and there's being charitable. OP clearly doesn't even *understand* the usage, so it seems pretty obvious the question is about the meaning rather than the origin. But both aspects are incredibly easy to look up - you don't even need to leave the Google homepage to see pretty much everything you could possibly want to know.

Comment: @1006a: Before it even lists any links, the Google homepage in my link above says *This idiom alludes to the song “Dixie” and the vain hope that the Confederacy, known as Dixie, would win the Civil War.* Do we *really* need a question on ELU to explore why it's ***whistling*** (rather than ***singing***, for example)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers That explanation just seems a little simplistic and potentially folk etymologic. In any case, the question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You ain’t just whistling Dixie, and that’s the truth! Whistling Dixie, which refers to a studied carelessness, comes from the song that originated in minstrel shows and from which the South takes its nickname. But if you say someone ain’t just whistling Dixie, it means they’re not kidding around. This is part of a [complete episode](https://www.waywordradio.org/whistling-dixie/).

[“Whistling Dixie” Origin](https://www.waywordradio.org/whistling-dixie-origin/)

Answer (score 3):

You've misinterpreted that sentence.  "Dixie" is a song.  You're whistling, and what you are whistling is the song called "Dixie".

The song and the idiom are both explained in a [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whistle--dixie) entry.

1. Also called Dixieland, Dixie Land. the southern states of the United States, especially those that were formerly part of the Confederacy.
2. any of several songs with this name, especially the minstrel song (1859) by D. D. Emmett, popular as a Confederate war song.
3. ...
4. ...
5. whistle Dixie, to indulge in unrealistically optimistic fantasies.

Comment: [Origins of Dixie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixie) "The word 'Dixie' refers to currency issued first by the Citizens State Bank (located in the French Quarter of New Orleans) and then by other banks in Louisiana.[6] These banks issued ten-dollar notes,[7] labeled "Dix", French for 'ten', on the reverse side. The notes were known as 'Dixies' by English-speaking southerners, and the area around New Orleans and the French-speaking parts of Louisiana came to be known as 'Dixieland'. Eventually, usage of the term broadened to refer to the Southern states in general.

Comment: I feel like this kind of gives half the answer and then stops. Okay, so it’s the song. But why does whistling (as opposed to singing?) a Confederate war song equal “indulging in unrealistically optimistic fantasies”? Because the Confederacy lost the war, so their battle song is inherently unrealistic? Why is it not unrealistic to sing Dixie, then, but only to whistle it?